# Deploy from github to Digital Ocean with Mina - hangs on "fetching commits"

Tags: ruby, ssh, digital-ocean, mina-deploy

I've added the server's SSH key to deploy keys in github.

After running `mina deploy` I get the following:

```
-----> Quiet sidekiq (stop accepting new work)
       /var/www/myproject/tmp/build-157262358827785
-----> Fetching new git commits
```

It stays here and nothing happens

When I press ctrl + c, it will say

```
-----> Mina: SIGINT received.
       Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
       Elapsed time: 1931.59 seconds
```

In my `deploy.rb` file I have `set :term_mode, nil` - people have said you need that for when it hangs up AFTER entering an SSH password, but I'm never primped until I do ctrl + c in the console.

There's no way to enter a password

Edit:

I did a `-v` flag for verbose output:

```
 -----> Quiet sidekiq (stop accepting new work)
       $ cd /var/www/myproject/current
       $ if [ -f /var/www/myproject/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid ] && kill -0 `cat /var/www/myproject/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid` > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                     RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec sidekiqctl quiet /var/www/myproject/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid
                   else
                     echo 'Skip quiet command (no pid file found)'
                   fi
       /var/www/myproject/tmp/build-157288289226943
-----> Fetching new git commits
       $ (cd "/var/www/myproject/scm" && git fetch "git@github.com:[company]/myproject.git" "dev:dev" --force)
```

doing `-s` for simulation shows this part is running

```
if [ ! -d "/var/www/myproject/scm/objects" ]; then
    echo "-----> Cloning the Git repository"
    git clone "git@github.com:[company]/myproject.git" "/var/www/myproject/scm" --bare
  else
    echo "-----> Fetching new git commits"
    (cd "/var/www/myproject/scm" && git fetch "git@github.com:[company]/myproject.git" "dev:dev" --force)
  fi &&
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I found this closed github issue: https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/issues/449

I found I simply needed to add `set :execution_mode, :system` to my deploy file.

The answer on the github issue says it's on the FAQ, however, their wording is the following:

```
- Mina hangs after i type my password in
Mina assumes that you have set up the communication with your server through the public/private keys, not password. If you want to use the password you will have to change the execution mode:
```

I was never even prompted for a password, so I didn't know this applied to me. I also AM using ssh public/private keys (obviously) so the way they worded this is strange. maybe it's because I'm not too experienced with this.

Anyway, in case someone has the same issue - here's the answer.